# Пропадают отзывы и оценки в Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Приложение выложено в GooglePlay. Люди его качают, оценивают и оставляют отзывы. Все отображается в Developer's консоли.

Однако, через некоторое время часть отзывов и оценок пропадает. Причем у людей в телефонах комменты и оценки остаются (смотрел сам) и приложение по прежнему установлено, а в статистику в консоли они не попадают.

Не могу понять - почему. Не гуглится. Возможно есть какая-то хитрость?

Comment: Напишите в поддержку, обычно отвечают в течение 2-3 дней

Comment: т.е. это проблема чисто технического характера? "Модерации" "подверглись" четыре совершенно разных приложения.

Comment: Может, кому пригодится ещё - достаточно развернутый ответ о политике Гугла.
https://qna.habr.com/q/844469

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это нормально. У гугла своя политика по отображению отзывов и оценок. Там все зависит даже от страны и языка.

Comment: спасибо) а есть где про такую политику почитать?

Comment: Я не нашел. Хотя честно говоря и не искал толком.